# How to extract data from archive with signature 789C?

Tags: c#, zip, zlib, sharpziplib

Google say what is this zip archive, but I cannot its extract by ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib and Zlib.net libraries.

Comment: How did you ask google to get that answer?

Comment: That is a zlib header.  What did you try with zlib that resulted in "I cannot its extract"?

Comment: var t = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream(input); and ZOutputStream outZStream = new ZOutputStream(output, zlibConst.Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);

Comment: That's not zlib, that's SharpZipLib.  What did you try with zlib that resulted in "I cannot its extract"?

Comment: Second sanmple is Zlib (ZOutputStream outZStream = new ZOutputStream(output, zlibConst.Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION))

Comment: That will compress.  Get rid of the `zlibConst`...

Comment: Also consider using [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) instead, which has a better interface to zlib.

Comment: Bellissimo)) DotNetZip for Zlib worked) Very thanks for you!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a zlib ([RFC 1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950)) header.  You can use the [zlib library](http://zlib.net/) to decompress it.

Answer (score 2):

I found offzip.exe at http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm to be super helpful to expand RFC 1950s.